# Angular chart doesn't show in my page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I followed all the tutorial, included all the js and css necessary, the html is according to the tutorial and the chart created in my js doesn't show in my page.

Css and JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ng-app and ng-controller:

```
<body class="container-full" ng-app="comando">

<div id=D12 class="col-md-12" ng-controller="fchart">
                <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"
                    chart-click="onClick">
                </canvas> 
            </div>
```

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('comando', ["chart.js"]);

app.controller("fchart", function ($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
});
```

I have no idea whatelse i can do. I aprecciate the help........

Comment: can you share us link of the tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143278/angular-chart-js-it-doesnt-display-the-chart?rq=1).

Comment: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/373) according to the github repo.
The solution is:

1. Upgrade the `angular-chart.js` library to latest version by uninstalling the current version and reinstalling the new version. Assuming you are using `bower` otherwise, remove the references to both the `Chart.js` library and the `angular-chart.js` library and then add the v 2.x of `Chart.js` and v 1.0.0-alpha6 of  `angular-chart.js` to your project and add the references in your `html` file

   `bower install angular-chart.js#1.0.0-alpha6 --save`
2. In your controller, add a reference to store chart Options

   `$scope.chartOptions={
         legend: { display: true, position: 'bottom' }
       };`
3. If you are utilizing the legend feature, In your `HTML` file make the changes to the directive as follows

Remove the `chart-legend` attribute and replace with `chart-options="chartOptions"`

`Example`

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"
                chart-click="onClick">
            </canvas>
```

Becomes

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="chartOptions" chart-series="series"
                chart-click="onClick">
            </canvas>
```

Comment: I find out that i did't include the script.js :x
but even I adding later the problem stayed the same. And i saw in the console the following error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=comando&p1=Error%3A…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)       angular.js:4587 

and at the line 4587:
throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}",